# Connect to Salesforce using Jsforce (Pure Javascript)

Tags: jsforce

I am trying to create a chrome extension for a specific usecase. I would like to know how to connect to salesforce using jsforce. I have tried access salesforce by creating a connected app and then connecting it with this code

```
 jsforce.browser.init({
        clientId: '***',
        clientSecret : '***',
        redirectUri: 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success'
      });
 jsforce.browser.login()
```

The very last line opens a salesforce login and after login I was unable to see any access token in browser object of jsforce. This is the response.
[image]

Any suggestions how i can work this out ?

Answer (score 1):

The redirectUri parameter must be set to the value of [chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/#method-getRedirectURL). This will be be in the form of `https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org/*`, which will be based on your app id. In other words, you'll need to configure your Connected App to use the same callback URL, as the app id shouldn't change once you've created it.

Comment: Do you have any example to refer ? I have used the same url which is mentioned above in redirectUri and as well as callback URL in connected app of salesforce

Comment: Now I have this error This site can’t be reached "kchfipgfdifaigccpgnjdhcgmndikofm.chromiumapp.org’s" DNS address could not be found. Diagnosing the problem. The one inside quotes is my local chrome extension